# Change color of row in DBGrid after OnCellClick event

Tags: delphi, colors, dbgrid

I want to change the color of the clicked row in a `DBGrid` in `OnCellClick` event and to save this state of the grid until the next `OnCellClick` event - than another row will be coloured etc. Does anyone know how I can achieve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it will be rly bad decision to code rendering inside `OnCellClick`.
Basically in `OnCellClick` you just simply need to save selected `RecNo`. Like this:

```
procedure TForm1.DBGrid1CellClick(Column: TColumn);
begin
  tag:=DBGrid1.SelectedField.DataSet.RecNo;
end;
```

And then u need to modify `OnDrawDataCell` func like this:

```
procedure TForm1.DBGrid1DrawDataCell(Sender: TObject; const Rect: TRect;  Field: TField; State: TGridDrawState);
begin
  if(Field.DataSet.RecNo=tag)then begin
    DBGrid1.Canvas.Brush.Color:=clYellow;
    DBGrid1.Canvas.Font.Color:=clNavy;
  end else begin
    DBGrid1.Canvas.Brush.Color:=clWhite;
    DBGrid1.Canvas.Font.Color:=clRed;
  end;
  DBGrid1.Canvas.FillRect(Rect);
  DBGrid1.DefaultDrawDataCell(Rect, Field, State);
end;
```

P.S. if u have multiple entries with same RecNo, u should choose another property, which will be unical for each row.

Comment: It's not colouring anything. It seems that I never enter the ``OnDrawDataCell`` event.

Comment: I have no code - I tried your solution and it's not colouring any rows at all.

Comment: Well, have you any data placed in DBGrid? =)
Which compiler you use? What OS? I just cant give you any suggestions, cuz i simply don't know what you have.
Anyways solution i've posted works fine for me, it was tested on WinXP*32 and Win7*64.

Comment: I have data from a ``mysql`` table called 'users' and it is being displayed in the ``OnActivate`` event of my form. OS is Win7*64. IDE is Delphi XE5.

Comment: Well, i have no XE5, but i've made example for u in Delphi7:
[link](http://markus13.name/s0me/fishfact.zip)
It works on my Win7*64.

P.S. it works with themes (uses ...XPman) too.

Comment: Thanks for the example - it does color the clicked row but when another row is being clicked the last clicked remains in yellow and I want to have only one coloured row in my grid. Is that possible ?

Comment: > it does color the clicked row but when another row is being clicked the last clicked remains in yellow

Well, on my PC it becomes white when i click another row.
Anyway u can try to add DBGrid1.Repaint in OnClick procedure.
Or u can try to turn DefaultDrawing property off.
Check [updated version](http://markus13.name/s0me/fishfact.zip)

Comment: Thanks for the help, man - now works just the way I want it :)